# Login Form w/ Ajax & PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, authentication

I needed to log into a database using jSON and Ajax to refresh it onto itself. Here is the fixed code to do so:

< auth.php >`

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

$("#login").click(function() {

    var action = $("#form1").attr('action');
    var form_data = {
        email: $("#email2").val(),
        password: $("#password").val(),
    };
$.getJSON("login.php",form_data,function(data){
    switch(data.retval){
      case 0: $("#form").html("You have logged in successfully,"+ data.data.displayName+"!");
      break;
      case 1: $("#status").html("Invalid Username/Password, please try again.");
      break;
      default: $("#status").html("Database error, please try again.");
      break;
   }
});
});
});
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="fullBG">
        <div id="formBG">
            <div id="form">
                <div id="status">
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>
                <form id="form1" name="form1" action="login.php" method="post">
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email2" size="30">
                    <br>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password"
                    size="30">
                    <br>
                    <input type="button" value="Login" class="sub" id="login">
                </form>
                <br />
                <br />
                <form method="link" action="register.php">
                    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="register">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>`
```

< login.php >`

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
mysql_connect('', '', '') or 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('phppro2') or
die ('Can\'t use database: ' . mysql_error());

// retval: 0 - login ok, 1 - login failed, 2 - internal error
$json = array("retval" => 2, "data" => NULL, "debug" => "");

$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['email']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['password']);

$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'";

$json['debug'] .= "SQL query was: ".$sql."\n";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
$json['debug'] .= "SQL query failed\n";
$json['debug'] .= "Other output: ". ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
die(json_encode($json));
}
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
$json['retval'] = 0;
$json['data'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
} else {
$json['retval'] = 1;
}
$json['debug'] .= "Other output: ". ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo json_encode($json);`
```

// Old problem:

I need to retrieve the information from my database and load it using Ajax. I had everything working, but my auth.php file was overwritten and I lost it. I tried to retrace my steps but I am getting lost. The page no longer refreshes onto itself and it does not retrieve the data. (I removed my database information, but it is connected)

My login.php I have not changed, so I assume it's accurate.

Comment: The only issue i can see is that you're not preventing the default action within `$("#login").click(function() {` to stop the form from submitting and the page redirecting. infact, it should just be `$('#form1').submit(function(){  return false });` where all your code comes before return false.

Comment: you have given same ID to two buttons

Comment: also switch statement missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you shouldn't keep same ID of two buttons (Register & Login Button)

2) change your javascript function as below

```
 $.getJSON("login.php",form_data,function(data){
        switch(data.retval){
          case 0: $("#form").html("You have logged in successfully,"+ data.data.displayName+"!");
          break;
          case 1: $("#status").html("Invalid Username/Password, please try again.");
          break;
          default: $("#status").html("Database error, please try again.");
          break;
       }
    }
```

3) Also your status div should have to be blank

```
<div id="status"></div>
```

4) syntax error on http://samaradionne.com/phppro2/auth.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#login").click(function() {

        var action = $("#form1").attr('action');
        var form_data = {
            email: $("#email").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
        };
 $.getJSON("login.php",form_data,function(data){
        switch(data.retval){
          case 0: $("#form").html("You have logged in successfully,"+ data.data.displayName+"!");
          break;
          case 1: $("#status").html("Invalid Username/Password, please try again.");
          break;
          default: $("#status").html("Database error, please try again.");
          break;
       }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: The two ID's were definitely an oversight, I meant to put it only on the login. 

Also why is it data.data ?

I changed this code but it is still not working. The "Invalid Username/Password, please try again." shows up automatically before any information is submitted.

Comment: @erraziB ahh. ok. wanted to bring your attention

Comment: one more thing was missing. edited my answer.. need to pass form_data

Comment: /facepalm I forgot I had entered text in there. Fixed, also removed the error. Thanks! I'm still not getting the text to reload on the page though, only a debugging output on the submit.

Comment: I updated it again, no syntax error in the code. Still nothing being sent to the status div.

Comment: I changed input type="submit" to "button", now it reloads onto itself but it is saying every user/pw is invalid.

Comment: see that json data coming into firebug: {"retval":1,"data":null,"debug":"SQL query was: SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='' and password='gggg'\nOther output: "}

Comment: you have email2 id of textbox and you have used email into javascript

Comment: I can't believe I did that mistake twice. I did it the first time around too!

I thank you greatly! I will update my code with the working version.